# Getting Server-side pagination using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Currently, I have a table in my view class that is getting populated from my database. To populate this data I have a controller class that is fetching all the data and after that, I'm including the following code in my view class to show all my data:

```
<table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
                     <thead>  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="35%">First Name</th>  
                               <th width="35%">Last Name</th>  
                          </tr>  
                     </thead>  
                </table> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({  
           "processing":true,  
           "serverSide":true,  
           "order":[],  
           "ajax":{  
                url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'contacts/fetch_user'; ?>",  
                type:"GET"  
           },  
           "columnDefs":[  
                {  
                     "targets":[0, 3, 4],  
                     "orderable":false,  
                },  
           ],  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

Controller class:

```
function fetch_user(){  
        $this->load->model("contacts_model");  
        $fetch_data = $this->contacts_model->make_datatables();  
        $data = array();  
        foreach($fetch_data as $row)  
        {  
             $sub_array = array();  
             $sub_array[] = $row->firstname;  
             $sub_array[] = $row->lastname;  
             $data[] = $sub_array;  
        }  
        $output = array(  
             "draw"                    =>     intval($_GET["draw"]),  
             "recordsTotal"          =>      $this->contacts_model->get_all_data(),  
             "recordsFiltered"     =>     $this->contacts_model->get_filtered_data(),  
             "data"                    =>     $data  
        );  
        echo json_encode($output);  
        $this->load->view('crm/contacts/test',$data);
   }
```

Model Class:

```
function make_query()  
      {  
           $this->db->select("*");  
           $this->db->from("crm_contacts");  
           if(isset($_GET["order"]))  
           {  
                $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[$_GET['order']['0']['column']], $_GET['order']['0']['dir']);  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');  
           }  
      }  
      function make_datatables(){  
           $this->make_query();  
           if($_GET["length"] != -1)  
           {  
                $this->db->limit($_GET['length'], $_GET['start']);  
           }  
           $query = $this->db->get();  
           return $query->result();  
      }  
      function get_filtered_data(){  
           $this->make_query();  
           $query = $this->db->get();  
           return $query->num_rows();  
      }       
      function get_all_data()  
      {  
           $this->db->select("*");  
           $this->db->from("crm_contacts");  
           return $this->db->count_all_results();  
      }
```

Now whenever I pass this URL `http://localhost/contacts/fetch_user?length=10&start=10&draw=9`, my output look like this:

[image]

Where its showing all the values as a JSON at the top and not in my actual table where it just shows Processing.

Comment: it does what you wrote: `echo json_encode($output); `

Answer (score 0):

As I've checked your problem, I've found that you are using the GET method for Ajax call. Actually, this data table used the POST method for processing data. You can send POST requests in ajax URL, for more details checkout server-side processing in data table manual link: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've updated my answer for more details